# Mopidy with pipewire-pulse

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, mpd, gstreamer

I run Mopidy as a service for my mpd because of the nice Spotify integration. I've followed the documentation's instructions to use it with pulseaudio by setting

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1`
```

in my `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and

```json
[audio]
output = pulsesink server=127.0.0.1
```

in my `/etc/mopidy/modipy.conf`.
All of this was working perfectly, however recently I've started using Pipewire as a replacement for PulseAudio on Arch Linux by following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PipeWire) and installing `pipewire`,`pipewire-alsa`, `pipewire-pulse` and `pipewire-media-session`. But now I've noticed that whenever I try to play any music nothing happens. I checked the journalctl for Mopidy and found this

```
ERROR ... [536:MainThread] mopidy.audio.gst
... mopidy[536]:   GStreamer error: Failed to connect: Connection refused
... mopidy[536]: WARNING ... [536:Audio-2] mopidy.audio.actor
... mopidy[536]:   Setting GStreamer state to GST_STATE_PLAYING failed
... mopidy[536]: WARNING ... [536:Core-11] mopidy.core.tracklist
... mopidy[536]:   Track is not playable: local:track:...
```

I searched around and found the `gst-plugin-pipewire` package, but installing it didn't help at all. Apart from Mopidy, everything else audio-wise is working perfectly. If I could get some help with this I'd be thankful.

Comment: Please have a look here https://github.com/mopidy/mopidy/issues/1974#issuecomment-797105715 If you have some suggestions, write it down in this conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the bellow and then `output = pulsesink client-name=mopidy` worked; I run mopidy as an *user* service.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install pipewire pipewire-pulse pipewire-media-session-pulseaudio pipewire-audio-client-libraries gstreamer1.0-pipewire libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-jack
```